# class field theory for K-groups of number fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Let $F$ be a number field. The classical class field theory gives an isomorphism between the ideal class group $Cl(F)$ and $\mathrm{Gal}(H/F)$, where $H$ is the Hilbert class field  (maximal unramified abelian extension) of $F$. Recall that  $Cl(F)$ is the torsion part of $K_0(\mathcal{O}_F)$. 
Quillen and Borel determined the abelian group structure of higher K-groups of $\mathcal{O}_F$. We also knot that they are finitely generated and its size of torsion part is connected with zeta-values like ideal class groups.

My question: do we have a ''class field theory'' describing the  (torsion part) of higher K-groups of $\mathcal{O}_F$ by some ''higher Hilbert class field''?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1990.1/Main/icm1990.1.0419.0428.ocr.pdf) should be what you're looking for.

Comment: So in their paper, on page 422, they speak of the "most important two-dimensional local field", which they write as $(\varprojlim_n\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}[[q]][q^{-1}])\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$, doesn't even seem to be a field. Ie, what they describe seems to be $\mathbb{Z}_p((q))[1/p]$. For example, the element $p+q$ doesn't seem to have an inverse - the coefficients of the inverse would have "unbounded denominators". What's going on here?

Comment: @oxeimon My impression is that the inverse limit $\varprojlim_n \mathbb Z / p^n \mathbb Z [[q]] [q^{-1}]$ is not $\mathbb Z_p ((q))$, because the inverse limit contains formal power series in $q$ with infinitely many nonzero negative terms, as long as they tend to zero. For example, $\sum_{n \le 0} p^n q^{-n}$ is in the inverse limit, but not in $\mathbb Z_p ((q))$.

Comment: @user94041 You mean $\sum_{n\geqslant0}$?

Comment: It's worth noting that the K-groups that (conjecturally) appear as zeta-values are Quillen K-groups, while Kato's article concern Milnor K-groups.

Comment: The link to the paper is now broken. Can anyone post a new link and/or give a full reference?

Comment: @HenriJohnston:  I have posted a copy here: http://www.landsburg.com/kato.generalizedclassfieldtheory.pdf